# Incorrect syntax in SQL Server update query

Tags: sql-server

What's wrong in the below update query. The error message is

> Incorrect syntax near 'SD'.

Code:

```
UPDATE T_EmpSelf_Details SD, T_TravelDetails TD 
SET SD.Host_Country = TD.New_Host_Country 
WHERE 
    SD.EL_Year = TD.EL_Year 
    AND SD.Emp_ID = TD.EmpId 
    AND SD.Staff_number IN ('00002080', '00002320');
```

Comment: What is the error message? (in full), EDIT the question and include it there please.

Comment: Below is the error message
Incorrect syntax near 'SD'.

Comment: look for the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53953158/edit) link underneath the question:  use that

Comment: You can only `update` one table at time. The error is at `,` (comma).

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to over complicate things... There's no need for CTEs, derived tables or sub-queries...

```
UPDATE SD SET
    SD.Host_Country = TD.New_Host_Country
FROM
    T_EmpSelf_Details SD
    JOIN T_TravelDetails TD
        ON SD.EL_Year = TD.EL_Year
        AND SD.Emp_ID = TD.EmpId
WHERE
    SD.Staff_number IN ('00002080', '00002320');
```

This syntax also has the added benefit of allowing you to write the query as a SELECT, verify the that your predicate is correct, and then easily convert it to an UPDATE...

```
/* begin by writing it as a SELECT... */
SELECT 
    SD.Host_Country, 
    TD.New_Host_Country
FROM
    T_EmpSelf_Details SD
    JOIN T_TravelDetails TD
        ON SD.EL_Year = TD.EL_Year
        AND SD.Emp_ID = TD.EmpId
WHERE
    SD.Staff_number IN ('00002080', '00002320');


/* when you're satisfied that the correct rows & values are in scope. convet it to an UPDATE...
-- begin by writing it as a SELECT... */

--SELECT 
--  SD.Host_Country, 
--  TD.New_Host_Country
UPDATE SD SET
    SD.Host_Country = TD.New_Host_Country
FROM
    T_EmpSelf_Details SD
    JOIN T_TravelDetails TD
        ON SD.EL_Year = TD.EL_Year
        AND SD.Emp_ID = TD.EmpId
WHERE
    SD.Staff_number IN ('00002080', '00002320');
```

Answer (score 0):

try using a common table expression instead:

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT
        SD.Host_Country
      , TD.New_Host_Country
    FROM T_EmpSelf_Details SD
    INNER JOIN T_TravelDetails TD ON SD.EL_Year = TD.EL_Year
        AND SD.Emp_ID = TD.EmpId
    WHERE SD.Staff_number IN ('00002080', '00002320')
)
UPDATE cte
SET Host_Country = New_Host_Country
;
```

Please note that over 25 years ago ANSI standards formalized join syntax. Try to adopt this syntax, start by denying yourself the use of commas between tables names in the from clause.

A different approach to your update statement would be as follows:

```
UPDATE SD
SET SD.Host_Country = TD.New_Host_Country
FROM T_EmpSelf_Details SD
INNER JOIN T_TravelDetails TD
    ON SD.EL_Year = TD.EL_Year
    AND SD.Emp_ID = TD.EmpId
WHERE SD.Staff_number IN ('00002080', '00002320');
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, You can update only one Table at a time using an Update Query, Hence you can have only one table name Specified Between the `UPDATE` and `SET` Keywords.

but here in your Code, you have specified 2 Tables (Even if you are only updating one).

So Instated This can be achieved using a simple Inner Join Like this

```
UPDATE SD -- Name/Alias of the Table to be updated 
    SET
        Host_Country=TD.New_Host_Country 
    FROM T_EmpSelf_Details SD
        INNER JOIN T_TravelDetails TD 
            ON SD.EL_Year=TD.EL_Year 
        WHERE  SD.Emp_ID=TD.EmpId 
            AND SD.Staff_number in ('00002080','00002320');
```

Answer (score -1):

The Error is correctly pointed by @Alex Kudryashev that trying to update 2 tables at once . corrected SQL:

```
UPDATE
      T_EmpSelf_Details SD
      INNER JOIN T_TravelDetails TD ON (
        SD.EL_Year = TD.EL_Year
        and SD.Emp_ID = TD.EmpId
      )
    SET
      SD.Host_Country = TD.New_Host_Country
    where
      SD.Staff_number IN ('00002080', '00002320');
```

query is validated at https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/